# Error failed to load build tools 25.0.1

Tags: javascript, java, android, c++, xml

I am new to Android studio and trying to make a simple app.
But there is a error massage
 'failed to load build tools 25.0.1'
I have download all SDK tools update.
Please help me

Comment: If you downloaded `3.0.0` or newer you can not use tools which are below `26.0.0` so you need to upgrade your build tools

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

> Go to File > Project Structure > Select Module > Properties you will
>   landing to this screen

[image]

Select Build Tools Version same as version selected in Compile Sdk Version.

Hope this will resolve your issue.